# Why are the electronegativities of elements in the middle of the transition groups quite high compared to surrounding elements?

Tags: transition-metals, electronegativity

Is it something to do with the d orbital being used, and if so, what effect does this have and why does it make the electronegativity higher?

Comment: Or maybe http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33611/why-are-there-peaks-in-electronegativities-in-d-block-elements is a better dupe?